# Multiple Update Not Working Laravel using save()

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

i am trying to do multiple update but i can only update the last record.
**`userIDs`** is basically id of users that i have to update status and it has more then 1 Ids.

```
$Users = User::all();
    foreach ($Users as $User) {

        foreach ($userIDs as $user_id) {

            if ($user_id == $User->id) {
                echo '<br/>';
                echo $user_id;
                $User->has_rotas = 1;

            } else {
                $User->has_rotas = 0;
            }

        }
        $User->save();
    }
```

Comment: because your $user->save() is outside the inner loop

Comment: @DhavalChheda: how can that be reason? its running for its iteration, or may be i am missing something?

Comment: Why don't you do `User::whereIn("id", $userIDs)->update(["has_rotas"=>1])`, (and one more for the rest?)

Comment: you need to show more code than this to understand what is the mistake that there might be there

Comment: @apokryfos: sure will do that, if nothing else works, thanks

Comment: You can use `in_array()` instead of the second loop. Not sure if it will solve your problem or not but I think it will be more simple and clear that way.

Comment: You're constantly changing in_rotas for the same user, so it will almost always end up as 0. Set it at the beginning of the initial loop, and only change it in the if statement.